# Modify a SSH command via Python

Tags: python, ssh, copy

After establishing an SSH connection  I've tried the following command to move a file from one folder to another one and renaming it:

```
command='cp /test/trial test/attempt/trial_something'  
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
```

and it worked.
Now I've tried, without success, to modify the command in this way:

```
command_test='/test/trial'
command='cp command_test test/attempt/trial_something'  
print (command)
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
```

the result of the print is

> cp command_test test/attempt/trial_something

so basically the string is not build as the one in first example.

Comment: instead of ssh, you can use os.system()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found a way:

```
command_test='/test/trial'
command='cp ' + command_test + ' test/attempt/trial_something'  
print (command)
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
```

this worked to me.